# Centre 3 columns within container but allow

Tags: css

I have a container that holds multiple divs, around 20. I want to put 3 divs on each line so it kind of looks something like this (with the divs just continuing to flow).

What's the best way to centre these columns without having them in some sort of parent div? I can center them if I used a div which held 3 columns each but with the system I'm using I cannot. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? can you share some code.

Comment: *"I have a container that holds multiple divs, around 20"* seems to conflict with *"What's the best way to centre these columns without having them in some sort of parent div?"*. The "container" would be the parent, and you can use a bunch of techniques to center boxes like this. Post the code you're working with and what you've tried if you want us to help.

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Comment: no code, no chocolate ! ... 20 divs alone ? well there at least in body wich is the parent container ... explain and show what you tried and failed. It wll help you to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example will be:

pure css you can use this one to control row:

```
.child:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

with `width: calc((100% - 60px)/3);` to get width dynamically.

```css
.child {
  background: white;
  height: 40vh;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  width: calc((100% - 60px)/3);
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.child:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}

.wrapper {
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' way IMO is to use flexbox. You say with no parent div but it has to have some kind of parent container div.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 25px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}

.box {
 display: block;
 height: 160px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```